# Casting uint64 to uint32 and truncation

Tags: c++, unsigned, truncation

When we cast an `uint64_t` to an `uint32_t`, I see by reading cppreference that truncation happens.

But, what bits are truncated? The higher or lower bits?
How is this decided, and why?

Answer (score 4):

The resulting value is the unique value equal to the original one modulo 2<sup>32</sup> that can be represented by `uint32_t`. In other words, only the 32 least significant bits in the base-2 representation of the value remain and all others (in your case the 32 most significant bits) are truncated.

Whether these bits are high or low (or neither) in the object representation of `uint64_t` is implementation-defined and depends especially on the endianess of the architecture.

Comment: Modulo 2³² will give you the *least* significant bits, not the most significant ones.

Comment: @MarkRansom Yes, but I don't see how that is inconsistent with the rest of my answer?

Comment: Oh I see, I missed that part. Thanks!

Comment: Why does it matter if your answer is consistent or not if it's just plain wrong?

Comment: @MarkRansom I can't tell from your comment what you think is wrong in my answer.

Comment: I'm not sure, but I think thee standard may call for explicit narrowing conversions to be rounded toward zero or to be implementation defined behavior.  I think you may need to state which compiler this is true for.

Comment: @Wyck No, integer conversion to an unsigned type has always been exactly specified in both C and C++.